# Getting the Circle of Death on Product page of 2nd store only

Tags: loading

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

We had some trouble setting up multi-domain/websites on Magento 2.4.2-p1. That was finally sorted by our hosting company but shortly after, we started getting the Circle of Death on the Product page of our 2nd store only. It also appears to be intermittent. I pulled the logs when it was happening yesterday and found the following:

debug.log:

```
[2021-10-19 21:51:34] main.DEBUG: URI '/index.php/wishlist/index/add/product/1776/form_key/mzDrJ82AjASBV0J5/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add) [] []
[2021-10-19 21:51:34] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/ourWEBSITEalias/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []
```

Exception.log:

```
[2021-10-19 01:24:41] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory {"report_id":"87280025f406f30d5ab1bf82d2fbfb7fe0b1d6933e6b18e638f69bb03553efdf","exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/ourWEBSITEalias/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/ourWEBSITEalias/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []
[2021-10-19 01:24:43] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory {"report_id":"b3051ef89675ea9144cfe5abddf568ee1e6879987ae3ecf265f9b692cb4a7015","exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/ourWEBSITEalias/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/ourWEBSITEalias/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []
```

System.log:

```
2021-10-19 21:52:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
```

**Why is this happening and what is the best way to fix it?** *Is there anything else in these logs I need to worry about?*

---

UPDATED on October 21st, 2021:

These are Errors I found in my `More Tools > Developer Tools > Console Tab`

```
MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
addthis_widget.js:70 The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline''
(anonymous) @ addthis_widget.js:70
addthis_widget.js:70 The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline''
(anonymous) @ addthis_widget.js:70
gourmet_0.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
www.myWEBSITE.com/:1 [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-52979727-1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com www.paypalobjects.com js.braintreegateway.com www.paypal.com geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.sandbox.paypal.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com *.vimeocdn.com www.youtube.com www.google.com/recaptcha/ www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ *.payments-amazon.com *.payments-amazon.co.uk *.payments-amazon.co.jp *.payments-amazon.jp *.payments-amazon.it *.payments-amazon.fr *.payments-amazon.es *.payments-amazon.de *.trackedlink.net *.trackedweb.net *.dotdigital-pages.com cdn.dnky.co api.comapi.com webchat.dotdigital.com assets.braintreegateway.com c.paypal.com pay.google.com api.braintreegateway.com api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com *.googleapis.com *.addthis.com *.moatads.com *.addthisedge.com *.facebook.com *.pinterest.com *.yotpo.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

addthis_widget.js:70 The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline''
(anonymous) @ addthis_widget.js:70
commons.js:93359 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
commons.js:4197 Download the Apollo DevTools for a better development experience: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm
jquery-migrate.js:23 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1
(index):555 Uncaught ReferenceError: mageplazaSearchProducts is not defined
    at (index):555
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
    at require.js:132
    at require.js:1156
    at each (require.js:57)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
    at Module.check (require.js:917)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
commons.js:38287 Object
commons.js:38404 Object Object
commons.js:38438 Object Object Object
content.js:11230 Error: there is no product
    at Object.prepareItemInfo (commons.js:38440)
    at init (content.js:11226)
init @ content.js:11230
content.js:11232 Error: there is no product
    at Object.prepareItemInfo (commons.js:38440)
    at init (content.js:11226)
init @ content.js:11232
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://pfjibkklgpfcfdlhijfglamdnkjnpdeg/index.esm.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://pfjibkklgpfcfdlhijfglamdnkjnpdeg/tooltip.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ecmgkhgjmodembdmiimbacpjgcdimiek/browser-polyfill.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://eidlalmjabcfgiimceghbmhjmhkpjclj/jquery.qtip.min.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
www.myWEBSITE.com/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://www.myWEBSITE.com/media/porto/configed_css/design_gourmet.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
www.myWEBSITE.com/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://www.myWEBSITE.com/media/porto/configed_css/settings_gourmet.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: check in browser console log

Comment: I'm quite sure that the code in the modules/theme has problem. It's due to an API call uses invalid method. Magento doesn't have wishlist API yet and it surely come from your modules/theme.

Comment: @Gohil Rajesh I have updated my original post with the Console log. Thank you for looking at that for me.

Comment: @PY Yick Thank you for that. Do you think it will be more Amasty's fault (that's where all of my extensions come from) or Smartwave Porto's fault (my theme). Smartwave also installed something called Layered Navigation from MagePlaza which I updated to the latest version (I hope I did anyways).

Comment: look like issue with mageplaza extension "(index):555 Uncaught ReferenceError: mageplazaSearchProducts is not defined"  please disable this extension and check one.. Note: disable it via SSH or config.php not from admin

Comment: in magento2 if any of critical js error in console then page loader always visible. so make sure all console error will fixed before go live